# Import textfiles into linked SQL Server tables in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import, text-files

I have an Access (2010) database (front-end) with linked SQL Server-tables (back-end). And I need to import text files into these tables. These text files are very large (some have more than 200.000 records, and approx. 20 fields)

The problem is that I can't import the tex tfiles directly in the SQL tables. Some files contain empty lines at the start, and some other lines that I don't want to import in the tables.
So here's what I did in my Access database:

**1)** I created a link to the text files.

**2)** I also have a link to the SQL Server tables

**3a)** I created an Append-query that copies the records from the linked text file to the linked SQLServer table.

**3b)** I created a VBA-code that opens both tables, and copies the records from the text file in the SQL Server-table, record for record. (I tried it in different ways: with DAO and ADODB).

[Step 3a and 3b are two different ways how I tried to import the data. I use one of them, not both. I prefer option 3b, because I can run a counter in statusbar to see how many records needs to be imported at any moment; I can see how far he is.]

The problem is that it takes a lot of time to run it... and I mean a LOT of time: 3 hours for a file with 70.000 records and 20 fields!
When I do the same with an Access-table (from TXT to Access), it's much faster.

I have 15 tables like this (with even more records), and I need to make these imports every day. I run this procedure automatically every night (between 20:00 and 6:00).

Is there an easier way to do this?
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is using SSIS an option?

Comment: Have you tried importing the data from a text file into a local Access table and then using a single `INSERT INTO LinkedTable SELECT * FROM LocalTable` to copy the data to the SQL Server table?

Comment: You can always accept the answer, if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 2):

This feels like a good case for [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) to me.

You can create a data flow from a flat file (as the data source) to a SQL DB (as the destination).

You can add some validation or selection steps in between.

You can easily find tutorials like [this one](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/211/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-data-flow/) online.

**Alternatively**, you can do what Gord mentioned, and import the data from a text file into a local Access table and then using a single `INSERT INTO LinkedTable SELECT * FROM LocalTable` to copy the data to the SQL Server table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to make some time to study the SSIS-option.


For now I have imported the textfile into a local Access database and run an append query to add these records in the SQL Server table. (just like Gord mentioned)

Thanks for your support! :)

Comment: Okay. I've added Gords alternative to the answer and upvoted his comment.